# MySQL Query Products have multiple sizes and prices

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento

I have following problem. I have 2 tables 'products' and 'productprices'. Each product has multiple prices i.e. ProductID 1 , SizeID 1, Price 4.00 | ProductID 1 , SizeID 2 , Price 5.50.

This is my current query...

```
SELECT  products.*, 
        productprices.Price 
FROM  products 
INNER JOIN productprices ON products.ID = productprices.ProductID 
WHERE products.Category='" . $categoryName . "'"
```

But I only want to return ONE record with lowest price for each product.

Can someone help ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into the `group by` clause and `aggregate functions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a self join `productprices` on the minimum of your product price

```
SELECT  p.*, 
        pp.*
FROM  products p
INNER JOIN productprices pp ON p.ID = pp.ProductID 
JOIN 
( SELECT ProductID ,MIN(price) price
 FROM productprices GROUP BY ProductID ) pp1
ON(pp.ProductID =pp1.ProductID AND pp.price = pp1.price)
WHERE p.Category='" . $categoryName . "'"
```

or if you don't need the whole row from `productprices` which has minimum price you can simply use `MIN()` function on your current query

```
SELECT  p.*, 
        MIN(pp.Price) price 
FROM  products p
INNER JOIN productprices pp ON p.ID = pp.ProductID 
WHERE p.Category='" . $categoryName . "'"
GROUP BY p.ID
```

Comment: Thnaks for help first solution works fine where the second one returns only one product for the entire category ! thanks again !